# What does this ternary operator do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have trouble in understanding what this ternary operator does in the snippet below. could someone help me understand. thanks.

```
const style = !isSaving
    ? {}
    : canAssign
    ? { cursor: 'pointer' }
    : { cursor: 'not-allowed'};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sets the value of style:

- if the negation of isSaving is true, style is {}
- if the negation of isSaving is false, style depends on canAssign
- if canAssign is true, it sets the cursor to pointer
- if canAssign is false, it sets the cursor to not-allowed

Answer (score 1):

If isSaving is true then return {} else check if canAssign is true. If it is then return { cursor: 'pointer' } else return { cursor: 'not-allowed ' }